# Cannot read property of “pool” undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to switch my pool server from http to https and my charts on my website are not working.

This is what i get...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pool' of undefined
>   at /home/"user"/pool/lib/charts.js:149:30
>   at ClientRequest. (/home/"user"/pool/lib/apiInterfaces.js:39:9)
>   at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>   at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:9)
>   at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>   at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)

chart.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var http = require('https');
var apiInterfaces = require('./apiInterfaces.js')(config.daemon, config.wallet, config.api);

var logSystem = 'charts';
require('./exceptionWriter.js')(logSystem);

log('info', logSystem, 'Started');

function startDataCollectors() {
    async.each(Object.keys(config.charts.pool), function(chartName) {
        var settings = config.charts.pool[chartName];
        if(settings.enabled) {
            setInterval(function() {
                collectPoolStatWithInterval(chartName, settings);
            }, settings.updateInterval * 1000);
        }
    });

    var settings = config.charts.user.hashrate;
    if(settings.enabled) {
        setInterval(function() {
            collectUsersHashrate('hashrate', settings);
        }, settings.updateInterval * 1000)
    }
}

function getChartDataFromRedis(chartName, callback) {
    redisClient.get(getStatsRedisKey(chartName), function(error, data) {
        callback(data ? JSON.parse(data) : []);
    });
}

function getUserHashrateChartData(address, callback) {
    getChartDataFromRedis('hashrate:' + address, callback);
}

function convertPaymentsDataToChart(paymentsData) {
    var data = [];
    if(paymentsData && paymentsData.length) {
        for(var i = 0; paymentsData[i]; i += 2) {
            data.unshift([+paymentsData[i + 1], paymentsData[i].split(':')[1]]);
        }
    }
    return data;
}

function getUserChartsData(address, paymentsData, callback) {
    var stats = {};
    var chartsFuncs = {
        hashrate: function(callback) {
            getUserHashrateChartData(address, function(data) {
                callback(null, data);
            });
        },

        payments: function(callback) {
            callback(null, convertPaymentsDataToChart(paymentsData));
        }
    };
    for(var chartName in chartsFuncs) {
        if(!config.charts.user[chartName].enabled) {
            delete chartsFuncs[chartName];
        }
    }
    async.parallel(chartsFuncs, callback);
}

function getStatsRedisKey(chartName) {
    return config.coin + ':charts:' + chartName;
}

var chartStatFuncs = {
    hashrate: getPoolHashrate,
    workers: getPoolWorkers,
    difficulty: getNetworkDifficulty,
    price: getCoinPrice,
    profit: getCoinProfit
};

var statValueHandler = {
    avg: function(set, value) {
        set[1] = (set[1] * set[2] + value) / (set[2] + 1);
    },
    avgRound: function(set, value) {
        statValueHandler.avg(set, value);
        set[1] = Math.round(set[1]);
    },
    max: function(set, value) {
        if(value > set[1]) {
            set[1] = value;
        }
    }
};

var preSaveFunctions = {
    hashrate: statValueHandler.avgRound,
    workers: statValueHandler.max,
    difficulty: statValueHandler.avgRound,
    price: statValueHandler.avg,
    profit: statValueHandler.avg
};

function storeCollectedValues(chartName, values, settings) {
    for(var i in values) {
        storeCollectedValue(chartName + ':' + i, values[i], settings);
    }
}

function storeCollectedValue(chartName, value, settings) {
    var now = new Date() / 1000 | 0;
    getChartDataFromRedis(chartName, function(sets) {
        var lastSet = sets[sets.length - 1]; // [time, avgValue, updatesCount]
        if(!lastSet || now - lastSet[0] > settings.stepInterval) {
            lastSet = [now, value, 1];
            sets.push(lastSet);
            while(now - sets[0][0] > settings.maximumPeriod) { // clear old sets
                sets.shift();
            }
        }
        else {
            preSaveFunctions[chartName]
                ? preSaveFunctions[chartName](lastSet, value)
                : statValueHandler.avgRound(lastSet, value);
            lastSet[2]++;
        }
        redisClient.set(getStatsRedisKey(chartName), JSON.stringify(sets));
        log('info', logSystem, chartName + ' chart collected value ' + value + '. Total sets count ' + sets.length);
    });
}

function collectPoolStatWithInterval(chartName, settings) {
    async.waterfall([
        chartStatFuncs[chartName],
        function(value, callback) {
            storeCollectedValue(chartName, value, settings, callback);
        }
    ]);
}

function getPoolStats(callback) {
    apiInterfaces.pool('/stats', callback);
}

function getPoolHashrate(callback) {
    getPoolStats(function(error, stats) {
        callback(error, stats.pool ? Math.round(stats.pool.hashrate) : null);
    });
}

function getPoolWorkers(callback) {
    getPoolStats(function(error, stats) {
        callback(error, stats.pool ? stats.pool.miners : null);
    });
}

function getNetworkDifficulty(callback) {
    getPoolStats(function(error, stats) {
        callback(error, stats.pool ? stats.network.difficulty : null);
    });
}

function getUsersHashrates(callback) {
    apiInterfaces.pool('/miners_hashrate', function(error, data) {
        callback(data.minersHashrate);
    });
}

function collectUsersHashrate(chartName, settings) {
    var redisBaseKey = getStatsRedisKey(chartName) + ':';
    redisClient.keys(redisBaseKey + '*', function(keys) {
        var hashrates = {};
        for(var i in keys) {
            hashrates[keys[i].substr(keys[i].length)] = 0;
        }
        getUsersHashrates(function(newHashrates) {
            for(var address in newHashrates) {
                hashrates[address] = newHashrates[address];
            }
            storeCollectedValues(chartName, hashrates, settings);
        });
    });
}

function getCoinPrice(callback) {
    apiInterfaces.jsonHttpRequest('www.cryptonator.com', 443, '', function(error, response) {
        callback(response.error ? response.error : error, response.success ? +response.ticker.price : null);
    }, '/api/ticker/' + config.symbol.toLowerCase() + '-usd');
}

function getCoinProfit(callback) {
    getCoinPrice(function(error, price) {
        if(error) {
            callback(error);
            return;
        }
        getPoolStats(function(error, stats) {
            if(error) {
                callback(error);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, stats.network.reward * price / stats.network.difficulty / config.coinUnits);
        });
    });
}

function getPoolChartsData(callback) {
    var chartsNames = [];
    var redisKeys = [];
    for(var chartName in config.charts.pool) {
        if(config.charts.pool[chartName].enabled) {
            chartsNames.push(chartName);
            redisKeys.push(getStatsRedisKey(chartName));
        }
    }
    if(redisKeys.length) {
        redisClient.mget(redisKeys, function(error, data) {
            var stats = {};
            if(data) {
                for(var i in data) {
                    if(data[i]) {
                        stats[chartsNames[i]] = JSON.parse(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            callback(error, stats);
        });
    }
    else {
        callback(null, {});
    }
}

module.exports = {
    startDataCollectors: startDataCollectors,
    getUserChartsData: getUserChartsData,
    getPoolChartsData: getPoolChartsData
};
```

apiInterfaces.js

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

function jsonHttpRequest(host, port, data, callback, path){
    path = path || '/json_rpc';

    var options = {
        hostname: host,
        port: port,
        path: path,
        method: data ? 'POST' : 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Length': data.length,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    var req = (port == 443 ? https : http).request(options, function(res){
        var replyData = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            replyData += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var replyJson;
            try{
                replyJson = JSON.parse(replyData);
            }
            catch(e){
                callback(e);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, replyJson);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e){
        callback(e);
    });

    req.end(data);
}

function rpc(host, port, method, params, callback){

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        id: "0",
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: method,
        params: params
    });
    jsonHttpRequest(host, port, data, function(error, replyJson){
        if (error){
            callback(error);
            return;
        }
        callback(replyJson.error, replyJson.result)
    });
}

function batchRpc(host, port, array, callback){
    var rpcArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        rpcArray.push({
            id: i.toString(),
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: array[i][0],
            params: array[i][1]
        });
    }
    var data = JSON.stringify(rpcArray);
    jsonHttpRequest(host, port, data, callback);
}


module.exports = function(daemonConfig, walletConfig, poolApiConfig){
    return {
        batchRpcDaemon: function(batchArray, callback){
            batchRpc(daemonConfig.host, daemonConfig.port, batchArray, callback);
        },
        rpcDaemon: function(method, params, callback){
            rpc(daemonConfig.host, daemonConfig.port, method, params, callback);
        },
        rpcWallet: function(method, params, callback){
            rpc(walletConfig.host, walletConfig.port, method, params, callback);
        },
        pool: function(method, callback){
            jsonHttpRequest('127.0.0.1', poolApiConfig.port, '', callback, method);
        },
        jsonHttpRequest: jsonHttpRequest
    }
};
```

Comment: At line `143` you write `callback(error, stats.pool ? Math.round(stats.pool.hashrate) : null);`, buth this won't work if the callback is called with an error,  in that case `stats` is `undefined`.  So the first thing you to check is, what the content of `error` is.

Comment: So how you suguest doing that?

Comment: Addign a break point or a `if(error) {console.dir(error)}` right before the `callback(error, stats.pool ? Math.round(stats.pool.hashrate) : null);` ?